# Is this the correct way to install memcache for Python?

Tags: memcached

1. Install Memcached
2. Install python-memcache library
3. Start Memcache service

Is that right?

What else is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would be better asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), the sister web site to this one that is for system administration sort of questions.